# How to get pixel transformation function in Photoshop

Tags: image-processing, photoshop, pixel

For Example,I have a Spider-Man Picture as the Original Picture，and I add a Gradient Map Effect to it in PhotoShop then I export it as my final picture.Here is my question:Is there a way that I can get a function which can tell us how to turn original pixel into final pixel? Does Photoshop have some Plugins to do so ? By the way，the transformation is not only the Gradient Map Effect but also all the Effects that PhotoShop has.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyUjc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVUcj.png)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is short and simple:

No.

You can reverse engineer some of the effects but that would only make sense if you wanted to create a 1:1 copy of PhotoShop. Otherwise it would be much easier to implement your own algorithms to achieve the effects.

You can see the difference between input and output values and for some linear operations it's quite simple to see what's going on but most effects will be non-linear which will make it nearly impossible to find out what exactly they do behind the scenes.

Comment: All right ! Thanks anyway.I tried to implement the algorithms,however it's not 100% the same as Photoshop does.That troubles me a lot！